# Is there a way to enter a negative seed in Minecraft for 3DS?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

This is a follow-up of my [previous question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/345587/finding-a-woodland-mansion-in-minecraft-3ds), where I was looking for an easily accessible woodland mansion. I have found that:

- seeds from Minecraft PE apparently work for Minecraft 3DS too
- seed [`-396676922`](https://www.pcgamesn.com/minecraft/best-minecraft-pocket-edition-seeds) spawns the player near a woodland mansion

However, when I enter the seed for a new world in Minecraft 3DS Edition, I get the following:

> [image]
>
> [image]

Is there any trick that would allow me to enter a negative seed there?

Comment: Not sure if it's possible to enter negative seeds for Minecraft: 3DS but I did find a positive seed that spawns you near a woodland mansion: 2511226758

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently **no way** to use negative seeds on the New Nintendo 3DS Edition of Minecraft. This is because there has never been a usage for the number pad needing a negative number.